# How to encrypt/decrypt using RSA/OAEP if we have public key only

Tags: c++, rsa, crypto++

I'm learning Crypto++ library. I've read lot of examples but didn't find how to encrypt/decrypt plain text message when the program has access to public key only, when the program not generates the keys.

```
CryptoPP::RSA::PublicKey pubKey;
pubKey.Load(CryptoPP::StringSource(SSL_PUB_KEY, true, new CryptoPP::Base64Decoder()).Ref());
CryptoPP::RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor e(pubKey);
```

But what to do after that?

Comment: You can encrypt but cannot decrypt with only the public key. That's the point of public key crypto.

Comment: As I know I can encrypt and decrypt as well using public key. But to decrypt the message must be encrypted using private key and to decrypt message encrypted with public key I just must use private key.

Comment: No, you can *sign* with a private key and *verify the signature* with a public key. Decryption with a public key just makes no sense. The point of encryption is to make message contents secret, but public keys are available to everyone by definition. If everyone can decrypt, there's no secrecy.

Comment: Yes, you're right, thanks. But question about encryption still actual.

Comment: Good choice with *`RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor`*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've get how to do it. I missundertood what RandonGenerator is and I thought that I have to get it from a key.

After that I do following:

```
CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool rng;
string cipher;
CryptoPP::StringSource ss1(stringToEncrypt, true, new CryptoPP::PK_EncryptorFilter(rng, e, new CryptoPP::StringSink(cipher)));
```

now we have encrypted data in `cipher`

Comment: I hate to split hairs, but your answer above does not answer your question of *"But what to do after that?"* You should show what you did. I'm guessing its going to have something to do with `PK_EncryptorFilter`, like [RSA Encryption Scheme (OAEP using SHA)](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RSA_Cryptography#Encryption_Scheme_.28OAEP_using_SHA.29) on the Crypto++ wiki.

Answer (score 2):

If you encrypt with public key, you decrypt it with private key. This is the whole point of rsa - asymmetric key encryption, you need key pair.

RSA also support "message signing" that you encrypt (usually a reduced MAC hash) with private key, but then you decrypt it with public key.

Comment: I fully understand how it works. I have both keys. The project contains two parts. One of those is implemented on C++ and it has public key only. Other part implemented on Java and it has private key. I'm looking how to encrypt message using public key. I've read this [article](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RSA_Cryptography#Encryption_Scheme_.28OAEP_using_SHA.29). But there's an example how to generate and encrypt/decrypt message. But I cannot understand how can I get `rng` variable if the program doesn't generate the keys.